# Not able to pass last inserted_id from parent serializer to children serializer with Django restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to save parent (VisVisits) and children (VisVistiData) table with same api call. Data is coming into json format. I am able to save both the table except one column `visit_id` in the children (VisVisitData) table. `visit_id` does not come from the json. It is auto number type field in parent table(VisVisits) and I want to take `visit_id` from parent(after gets insert) table and save it to their children ids with other column in children table (VisVisitData)

I really need help to fix this issue.

## Serializer

```
class VisVisitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = VisVisitDataSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = VisVisits
        fields = ('visit_id','user','data')
        read_only_fields = ['visit_id']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        visits_data = validated_data.pop('data')
        visit = VisVisits.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for visit_data in visits_data:
            VisVisitData.objects.create(visit_id=visit.visit_id, **visit_data)
        return visit


class VisVisitDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VisVisitData
        fields = ('__all__')
```

## model

```
class VisVisits(models.Model):
    visit_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UsrUsers, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.visit_id)

class VisVisitData(models.Model):
    vdata_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
    visit = models.ForeignKey('VisVisits', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='data')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vdata_id)
```

## json

```
{
  "user": "1",
  "visits": [
    {
      "action": "i",
      "local_id": "170",

      "data": [
        {
          "Active": "1",
          "LocalID": "1905",
          "VisitDataID": "",
        },
        {
          "Active": "1",
          "LocalID": "1906",
          "VisitDataID": "",
        },
        {
          "Active": "1",
          "LocalID": "1907",
          "VisitDataID": "",
        },
        {
          "Active": "1",
          "LocalID": "1908",
          "VisitDataID": "",
        },
        {
          "Active": "1",
          "LocalID": "1909",
          "VisitDataID": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So again, what exactly is the issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: I have fixed it. issue that I was trying to fix was to pass visit_id (which is auto increment type field) from visit table to its child table called visit_data. Both table was getting inserting from the same api link.

Comment: Well it wasn't visible from your code where exactly you needed help. And using the word fix, it sounded like you had an error/bug that needed fixing. 
In any case, it's good you already found a way to solve your problem, but what you needed was writable nested serializers. You can read that up in the DRF docs to learn how to handle creation of nested objects in the create method of the serializer. Although, I can see that you already figured that out which is why I was confused what your question was. You can put up an answer later in order not to confuse others